# Rows of one column shifting under other column in Pandas after str.split?

Tags: python, pandas, split, calculated-columns, data-wrangling

I'm cleaning data (from a csv file) in Pandas and one of the columns [pic of it's first 4 rows](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6eFC9.png) has hundreds of values (in each row) seperated by comma.

I use `str.split(',', expand=True)` and able to get the values spread across various columns. However, I'm seeing rows of one column shifting under other column (it can be seen in the pic [2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VIyaW.png)).

Is there any method to get the values under their respective columns?

Note: Each row is associated with unique ID.

I've been stuck on this problem for quite some time and couldn't resolve it. Any help would be highly appreciated!

Edit 1: TL;DR

-- Input -- First 2 rows of a column for an example--

```
{"crap1": 12, "NAME": "John", "AGE": "30","SEX": "M", "crap2": 34, ....... "ID": 01}

{"crap1": 56, "NAME": "Anna", "AGE": "25","SEX": "F", "crap2": 78, ....... "ID": 02}
```

-- Desired Output -- Derive 4 columns from 1, based on values in each row

```
NAME  | AGE | SEX | ID

John  | 30  |  M  | 01

Anna  | 25  |  F  | 02
```

Comment: please give example

Comment: done. please have a look now

Answer (score 1):

You can try expanding the column with multiple entries into a separate dataframe and then joining them back into the original dataframe.

```py
df2 = df.col1.str.split(',',expand=True)
```

During this, you can also drop the original column that you wanted to expand and also give the new columns.

```py
df2.columns = ['col2_%d'%idx for idx,__ in enumerate(df2.columns)]
df = df.drop(columns=['col1'])
df = pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
```

Since your example was an image, I couldn't test it out on that specific case. Here's a small working example to illustrate the idea  :D

```py
import pandas as pd

def get_example_data():
    df = pd.DataFrame(
        {
            'col1' : ['abc','def','ghi,jkl','abc,def','def'],
            'col2' : ['XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ','XYZ']
        }
    )
    return df


def clean_dataframe(df):
    # expand the column into a separate dataframe
    df2 = df.col1.str.split(',',expand=True)
    print(df2)

    # incase you would like to retain original column name : col1 --> col1_0,col1_1
    df2.columns = ['col1_%d'%idx for idx,__ in enumerate(df2.columns)]
    print(df2)

    # drop original column
    df = df.drop(columns=['col1'])

    # concat expanded column
    df = pd.concat([df,df2],axis=1)
    print(df)
    return df

if __name__=='__main__':
    df = get_example_data()
    print(df)
    
    df = clean_dataframe(df)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot Balagopal for such a detailed response. I agree with your approach. The problem, however occurs after I split the row by comma delimiter, the values aren't falling under their respective columns. I've added a pic of the original column values. Please have a look :)

Comment: Just realized that each row is a list of key value pairs. 1. If each row is a dictionary, concat all the dictionaries using ```pd.concat()``` to get your final DataFrame. 2. If the whole thing is a json which you want to convert to a pandas dataframe, directly use ```pd.read_json()```.